# Get NSInternalInconsistencyException Error when I try to add a row into my tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am updating my numberOfRowsInSection before I add the row so it cannot be that. I also have set the table's delegate and datasource in the viewDidLoad() method. I have no idea what else it could be.  The relevant code should be in the last two methods. For context, I am trying to add a row for every time a button is pressed in the tableview.

```
class LiveWorkoutViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var routineNameText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

//VARIABLES
var routine: Routine?
var setNumber = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exerciseTableView.delegate = self
    exerciseTableView.dataSource = self
    routineNameText.text = routine?.name
    exerciseTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    exerciseTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return setNumber

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:LiveWorkoutCell = self.exerciseTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LiveWorkoutCell") as! LiveWorkoutCell
    return cell
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (routine?.exercises.count)!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return routine?.exercises[section].name
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30))
    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 343, height: 30))
    doneButton.center = footerView.center

    doneButton.setTitle("Add Set", for: .normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.9176470588, green: 0.9411764706, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    doneButton.tag = section
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addSet(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    footerView.addSubview(doneButton)
    return footerView
}

@objc func addSet(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Add set!")
    print(sender.tag)
    setNumber += 1

    exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()

    exerciseTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: setNumber, section: sender.tag)], with: .automatic)

    exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Your data source needs to be updated before you insert the row.

Comment: exerciseTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: setNumber-1, section: sender.tag)], with: .automatic)

Comment: Please show the full error message. It gives good hints. Especially since it should be a basic one.

Comment: Unrelated but `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is useless for a single insert operation.

Comment: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself with some help from @Paulw11 comment.

Issue was that I was using the same variable to represent number of rows for all sections, thus when I added a row it was adding it for only one section but setNumber represented all sections. Solution is to insert rows for all sections or have a different method to represent numberforRows

Answer (score 0):

The first row in the table is 0 (ie. it is one less than the number of rows in the table).

Because you are incrementing `setNumber` before you call `insertRow`, the `row` you are passing is 1 higher than it should be; i.e. when `setNumber` is 1 you need to insert row 0, but you are inserting row 1.

You can simply increment `setNumber` after you insert the row.

```
@objc func addSet(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Add set!")
    print(sender.tag)

    exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()

    exerciseTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: setNumber, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    setNumber += 1

    exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: I got the same error doing that, but different reason:



`NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Comment: Rather than using `sender.tag` as the section, you should just have 0. You don't have different sections, that I can see

Comment: I’m implementing that later but that has zero effect on the code. Still getting the error :(

Comment: Get it working by just returning `0` for `numberOfSections` *or* you will need an array of integers to represent the number of rows you want in each section; right now you have more than 1 section but only a single integer for storing your row count